# In a comment, markdown inexplicably failed to turn SO URLs into links

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

In my third comment to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182579/constructor-in-c), I put in (one explicit, manually formatted link) and two URLs to other SO questions. Since the amount of characters in a comment is quite limited, and since I had to squeeze three links into that comment, I shortened these links to *`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/<ID>`*. (One of them has a superfluous `/` at the end.)
For reasons I don't understand, markdown failed to turn them into links. Note that markdown did not fail on marking `code`.

I have checked both links to be valid by copy-pasting them into my browser's address bar. There's nothing wrong with them.
I have also tried these links in test comments (which I deleted afterwards), and they both work fine there. Another test revealed that the sentence that contains them ("I've tagged [What is the member variables list after the colon in a constructor good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210616/) and [C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612) as `c++-faq`."), posted as its own comment, will have the URLs turned into links, too.

What could I have done wrong to make this fail?

Comment: Just a note, you can shorten the URL further by using http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/210616

Comment: @Barry: `http://stackoverflow.com/q/210616`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/210616. Thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: Wizz bang magical features strip out the http://www. gubbins for display purposes.

Comment: @Barry: SO doesn't have www.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>By design. You can no longer mix raw and markdown URLs in the same comment.</s>

Pick one way or the other per comment and stick to it.

With the recent addition of [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000), this was becoming unfeasible, hence we've spent some time to have a better way for fixing [this vulnerability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69879/comment-nofollow-exploit). So after the next build, multiple link styles in comments work again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Is there a rationale to this? Because, by default, I'd question a design decision that nobody is able to figure out for 13 hours until the site owner comes and explains it.

Comment: @sbi there was an exploit based on inappropriate mixing of URL parsers. It's a really odd thing to do on top of that IMHO; what is the valid use case for mixing markup styles in a *comment*?

Comment: I guess I can't argue with preventing exploits. `:)` Thanks for explaining!