# Comments not auto-linked when mixing raw links with Markdown links

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, markdown

Example: [C++ text file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954792/c-text-file-i-o)

The content in the comment had both raw `http://...` links, and `[markdown](http://...)` links:

```
Multiple similar questions i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808127/c-text-file-reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825553/convert-hex-string-to-hex-value -- I suggest you get yourself a good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).
```

In the result, the raw links are not clickable.

Comment: Odd. What did you use as separator between the two links?

Comment: @Pekka: A space.

Comment: Works for me if I copy&paste the comment. Strange

Comment: Test: Multiple similar questions i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808127/c-text-file-reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825553/convert-hex-string-to-hex-value -- I suggest you get yourself a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Test: Multiple similar questions i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808127/c-text-file-reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825553/convert-hex-string-to-hex-value -- I suggest you get yourself a good book

Comment: @Pekka, you are aware you did not copy `[the Markdown](link)`, right?

Comment: @Arjan sure, but I doubt whether he used that notation for the two broken links in this case?

Comment: @Arjan: True, but you really changed the question quite a bit with your edit -- enough that it's really not the same question anymore. Pekka's comments make sense for the original question in a way they do not with the question after your edit.

Comment: I hope in the end I didn't change the meaning of the question? Just tried to ensure folks saw *what* was in the comment. And yes, @Pekka, that's exactly what the code block with the evil scroll bar shows. ;-)

Comment: (To be more precise, @Pekka, the comment used some raw links and one Markdown link. Your test did not include the latter.)

Comment: @Arjan yeah, I see! +1 for your answer, this explains it.

Comment: @Arjan: What I mean is that with your edits, it now makes Pekka's comments not apply; obviously his test doesn't include the pattern mentioned in the question at this point because the question didn't indicate that pattern until the edit. Also, after the edit the question becomes an exact duplicate of the one indicated in your answer. I think the edit makes the question better describe what's going on which is why I've left it alone, but it certainly is significantly different than the question I originally asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [could not mix explicit and implicit linking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/in-a-comment-markdown-inexplicably-failed-to-turn-so-urls-into-links/70421#70421) for a while:

> By design. You can no longer mix raw and markdown URLs in the same comment.
>
> [...] there was an exploit based on inappropriate mixing of URL parsers

A better way of fixing this exploit was added in June '11; since then the mixing works again.