# URL in comment not linkified

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In a comment, markdown inexplicably failed to turn SO URLs into links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/in-a-comment-markdown-inexplicably-failed-to-turn-so-urls-into-links)

I just added [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360575/how-to-learn-all-these-client-side-tricks-that-are-used-on-the-web-today) (the 4th one) containing a hyperlink, *including* protocol and all other required elements, but the URL doesn't show up as a link, but as plain text, like:

> Amazon.com dropped the older comments, so those are only regarding the newest (6th) edition, which I haven't read yet. But as you're already experienced in other programming languages, I think you'll manage. A more down-level book is Nicholas Zakas' [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047022780X). Zakas is working on the third edition, at the moment. And if you want to learn some good, but heavy stuff, read http://perfectionkills.com/

(but the last link doesn't look and work like one). Is this a bug or does the comment parser get confused because I already included another hyperlink? Or is it because I almost reached the maximum number of characters allowed inside of a comment and the parser couldn't automatically translate my last URL to a link anymore, because it would run out of space when inserting proper markup?

Comment: Amazon.com dropped the older comments, so those are only regarding the newest (6th) edition, which I haven't read yet. But as you're already experienced in other programming languages, I think you'll manage. A more down-level book is Nicholas Zakas' [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047022780X). Zakas is working on the third edition, at the moment. And if you want to learn some good, but heavy stuff, read http://perfectionkills.com/

Comment: Well, the above is a reproduction of http://perfectionkills.com/ not rendering as a URL. I wonder if it's because it's at the end of the comment: http://perfectionkills.com/

Comment: Or, if perhaps, http://perfectionkills.com/ doesn't render because you [already included a URL link of a different syntax](http://perfectionkills.com/).

Comment: I changed the second link to Markdown syntax so that it won't look weird before the next deploy.

Comment: @mmyers: Great, thanks, but how did you do that? It wouldn't fit in the maximum of 600 characters.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: I made it `[http://perfectionkills.com/](http://perfectionkills.com/)` and it worked out to 599 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the issue is that you mixed link types, which you [can no longer do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/in-a-comment-markdown-inexplicably-failed-to-turn-so-urls-into-links/70421#70421). Since you have an inline Markdown link already, you need to make your second link into an inline Markdown link as well since the system intentionally avoids linkifying your raw URL in this case. As far as I know, the Markdown link always takes precedence, since I imagine the parser checks for links of that style first.

The FAQ entry on [how comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757) also covers this in the section "How can I format and link in comments?"

Comment: So, if I add a normal http://www.example.com link, I shouldn't use [these kind of links](http://www.example.com) (or the other way around).

Comment: I think you do recall correctly, as I also recall hearing about that functionality. Can't find where I first heard it, though.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel The Markdown link always takes precedence. Jeff (I think) describes the behaviour somewhere, looking for the source now.

Comment: I just made some changes today regarding this, so this will work again after the next build. /cc @Marcel